# Google map API doesn't work with const/let initMap function while it works fine for var initMap function

Tags: javascript, google-maps

If `initMap` function is `let` or `const` it won't work and throw error:

```
Qb {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError"}
```

If I replace it with `var`, it works fine. Why is that?

Here is my code.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>

        const initMap = function () {//THIS LINE
            // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
            let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 8
            });
        };

    </script>

    <!--map API-->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_HERE&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--header ends-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="map-wrapper">
            <div id="map" style="height: 300px; width: 600px"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will appreciate a comment on why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `const` and `let` variables do not become properties of `window`.

> This declaration creates a constant whose scope can be either global or local to the block in which it is declared. Global constants do not become properties of the window object, unlike var variables.

You can read more about it [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: If that is so, this code shouldn't work but it works fine: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wgsbemw5/)

Comment: @SKG but this doesn't https://jsfiddle.net/odyjzqot/ Your example works because both `<script>` elements are using the same context.

Comment: I get that. But are you saying Google API is looking for window.initMap? And not the global initMap?

Comment: @SKG Not necessarily, scripts loaded from files have a different context then the inline scripts.

Comment: Could you please link to a source regarding "different context"?

Comment: @SKG Actually, I've said that because I've run a test to check but my test was flawed (file script was loaded before the inline script), it seems that a script loaded from a file can access a `const` defined in an inline script (same context). So I guess the problem is that the google library is using `window.callbackFnName()` to run the callback function.